# Sidenav trigger not working on Safari/iOS PWA

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, materialize

I have an issue with a sidenav trigger on iOS/Safari. It just doesn't open the sidenav or react in any way. Has anyone had any similar issues with sidenavs and iOS/Safari? Also of note: I have another side-nav that is working just fine on Desktop/Chrome, the Android emulator, AND even works on iOS/Safari. The only discernible difference is that the icon to trigger a sidenav which is NOT working, is in a top nav, nav wrapper at the top of the app, where-as the one that is working on all devices is attached to an icon/button lower on the page.

I have tried putting the trigger class both directly on the icon, and wrapping the icon in an anchor tag with the trigger class. Both versions work on desktop/Chrome, and on an Android emulator, but NEITHER version works on iOS/Safari.

Here is the first NOT working sidnav trigger:

```
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a href="/">Food<span>Ninja</span></a>
      <span class="right grey-text text-darken-1">
        <a class ="sidenav-trigger" data-target="side-menu">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

The sidenav content:

```
  <!-- side nav -->
  <ul id="side-menu" class="sidenav side-menu">
    <li><a class="subheader">FOODNINJA</a></li>
    <li><a href="/" class="waves-effect">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/about.html" class="waves-effect">About</a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a href="/pages/contact.html" class="waves-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">mail_outline</i>Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The second sidenav trigger that IS working:

```
  <div class="center">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-small btn-large add-btn sidenav-trigger" data-target="side-form">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </a>
  </div>
```

And the second sidenav content content:

```
  <!-- add recipe side nav -->
  <div id="side-form" class="sidenav side-form">
    <form class="add-recipe container section">
      <h6 >New Recipe</h6>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input placeholder="e.g. Ninja soup" id="title" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="title">Recipe Title</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input placeholder="e.g. Tofu, mushroom, garlic" id="ingredients" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="ingredients">Ingredients</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field center">
        <button class="btn-small">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

The initialization script of materialize sidnav:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // nav menu
  const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.side-menu');
  M.Sidenav.init(menus, {edge: 'right'});
  // add recipe form
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.side-form');
  M.Sidenav.init(forms, {edge: 'left'});
});
```

To reiterate, both sidenavs work on Android emulator/chrome browser. Only the first sidenav class .side-menu does not work in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

same issue, try to set maximum-scale=1 in the content of viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
```